# Web application could not be started with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, eoferror

I'm trying to deploy a second rails app to a linux server but I'm getting a "Web application could not be started". Not sure where to look to even begin solving this.  Using Appache/passenger.  Virtual host setup is similar to other site that is running on server.  I do have a different IP address setup for new site. Also, the Ruby RVM file directory is being shared for the two apps. Here's the error output:

Web application could not be started

```
end of file reached (EOFError)
/home/bic/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/buffering.rb:174:in `sysread_nonblock'
/home/bic/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/buffering.rb:174:in `read_nonblock'
/home/bic/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:141:in `rbuf_fill'
/home/bic/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:122:in `readuntil'
/home/bic/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:132:in `readline'
/home/bic/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2563:in `read_status_line'
/home/bic/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2552:in `read_new'
/home/bic/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1320:in `block in transport_request'
/home/bic/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1317:in `catch'
/home/bic/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1317:in `transport_request'
/home/bic/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1294:in `request'
/home/bic/wwwroot/proposals/app/models/doctor.rb:61:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/bic/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:746:in `start'
/home/bic/wwwroot/proposals/app/models/doctor.rb:61:in `<top (required)>'
/home/bic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/home/bic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/home/bic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/home/bic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/home/bic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:359:in `require_or_load'
/home/bic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:313:in `depend_on'
/home/bic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_dependency'
/home/bic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:439:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
/home/bic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `each'
/home/bic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `block in eager_load!'
/home/bic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `each'
/home/bic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `eager_load!'
/home/bic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:53:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/home/bic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/home/bic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/home/bic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/home/bic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
/home/bic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/home/bic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
/home/bic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/home/bic/wwwroot/proposals/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
config.ru:3:in `require'
config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
/home/bic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
/home/bic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
config.ru:1:in `new'
config.ru:1:in `<main>'
/home/bic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/passenger-4.0.16/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:105:in `eval'
/home/bic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/passenger-4.0.16/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:105:in `preload_app'
/home/bic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/passenger-4.0.16/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:150:in `<module:App>'
/home/bic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/passenger-4.0.16/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
/home/bic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/passenger-4.0.16/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the problem.  I had added a model (doctor.rb) that was checking authentication and was no longer needed. Once I removed it everything worked correctly.